# Looping and adding extra properties to a Object

Tags: arrays, powershell, object, foreach

I'm running a simple script to check if several specific services are running on an array of computers. It works fine, except the each 'row' appears' for every iteration of the loop. In this case 3 times. How do I edit/add to a property of an existing object? I.e. I want to add extra properties for the same object/row...

```
ComputerName Qualys Cloud Agent SplunkForwarder Service Cb Defense
------------ ------------------ ----------------------- ----------
dc01         Found              Found                   Found     
dc01         Found              Found                   Found     
dc01         Found              Found                   Found     
dc02         Found              Found                   Found     
dc02         Found              Found                   Found     
dc02         Found              Found                   Found     
ds01         Found              Found                   Found     
ds01         Found              Found                   Found     
ds01         Found              Found                   Found
```

```
$ComputerName = 'dc01','ds01','dc02'
$ServiceList ='Qualys Cloud Agent',
              'SplunkForwarder Service',
              'Cb Defense'

$objarray = @()
$obj = @()
$ServiceArray = get-service -ComputerName $ComputerName -DisplayName $ServiceList  |  select-object -property MachineName,DisplayName,Name,Status

Foreach ($Computer in $ComputerName){

    $obj = New-Object PSObject
    $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "ComputerName" -Value $Computer

    Foreach($Service in $ServiceList){
        If ((gsv -computername $computer -displayname $Service).Status -eq 'Running'){
            #write-output "Found $Service on $Computer"
            $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name $service -Value 'Found'
            $objArray += $obj        
        }
        else{
            #write-output "Not  Found"
            $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name $service -Value 'Not Found'
            $objArray += $obj
        }
    }


}

$objarray | sort computername
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the `$objArray += $obj` statement outside the inner loop - this way each object is only referenced by the array *once*:

```
Foreach ($Computer in $ComputerName){
    $obj = New-Object PSObject
    $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "ComputerName" -Value $Computer

    Foreach($Service in $ServiceList){
        If ((gsv -computername $computer -displayname $Service).Status -eq 'Running'){
            #write-output "Found $Service on $Computer"
            $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name $service -Value 'Found'
        }
        else{
            #write-output "Not  Found"
            $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name $service -Value 'Not Found'
        }
    }
    
    # Only need to add the resulting object ONCE
    $objArray += $obj        
}
```

---

I personally prefer constructing each list of object properties as a dictionary, and then convert + output it at the very end of the loop - at which point we simply assign the result of *the entire `foreach()` statement* to the desired variable:

```
$objArray = foreach($Computer in $ComputerName){
    # Create dictionary to keep track of the new properties
    $props = [ordered]@{ ComputerName = $Computer}

    foreach($Service in $ServiceList){
        # Populate dictionary with remaining properties inside the inner loop
        if((gsv -computername $computer -displayname $Service).Status -eq 'Running'){
            $props["$service"] = 'Found'
        }
        else{
            $props["$service"] = 'Not Found'
        }
    }
    
    # convert to object, 
    [pscustomobject]$props
}
```

Comment: Thanks, moving the $objArray outside worked. What I really want to do is extend this by adding another few Properties/columns (e.g. QuaysVersion, SplunkVersion) is a dictionary (hashtable?) suitable for this?

Comment: @Aziz Yes, absolutely - just add them to the `$props` dictionary before casting to `[pscustomobject]`, like `$props['SplunkVersion'] = Get-SplunkVersion -ComputerName $computer` (replace `Get-SplunkVersion ...` with the actual expression you'd use to fetch the version)

Comment: I did it and yes the hashtable method is more intuitive and cleaner. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add a property to an object, pipe the object to "add-member".  Here is a quick example:

```
$files = Get-childitem "$env:USERPROFILE\Documents\*"
Foreach ($item in $files)
{
    $item | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "extention" -Value $item.Name.Substring($item.name.Length - 3)
}
$files.extention
```